# IIRF Regex for Domain-based rewrites

Tags: regex, iirf

I have seen a ton of examples for URL rewrites based on the subdomain, but I am trying to do URL rewrites based on the domain name itself, specifically serve content from a subfolder with the domain name in it.

For instance, I'd like

http://www.site1.com/sub/folders/long-html-filename.htm to be rewritten to
either
/sites/www.site1.com/sub/folders/long-html-filename.htm
or 
http://www.masterdomain.com/sites/www.site1.com/sub/folders/long-html-filename.htm

I've been able to do a lot of the rewrite regex on my own, but I am hitting a brick wall on this one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin - you were close. The IIRF author got me the rest of the way there:

```
RewriteRule ^/(?!sites/)(.*)$ /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Now I am just trying to figure out how to combine that with a forced-WWW RedirectRule.

Another stumbling block...I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www)[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$ [I]
RedirectRule ^/(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/(?!sites/)(.*)$ /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, I am just getting a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using %{HTTP_HOST} to capture the hostname? Maybe something like this would work:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /sites/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Comment: Some examples [here](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/63be1460-dbd0-4ad4-ad39-4b68352fe9a6.htm) showing how to grab the domain name, separate from the subdomain.